# Pass drop down list's selected value as a query string in an ActionLink in an MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have a simple drop down list in my view:

`@Html.DropDownList("ddlAppIds", new SelectList(ViewBag.AppIds))`

And right below it, I have an `ActionLink`.  I want to send the selected value of the above drop down list as a query string parameter inside this `ActionLink`:

`@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", new { id = selectedAppId })`

`selectedAppId` is just for demonstration purposes of what I want to hopefully accomplish.  How can I pass the drop down list's selected value as a query string parameter in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you happen to already have a selected value at page load, MVC has no way of knowing the user selects without a postback. Once the page has been sent to the client, MVC is done until the next request: your Razor view has already been rendered and no changes will be made to anything in the DOM without you manually doing it via JavaScript.

If you want to change the link based on the selected value, then you will need to write JavaScript to make that happen. Since you're using MVC, I'm going to assume jQuery support, because it's included by default:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlAppIds').on('change', function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('#IdForYourLink').prop('href', '/url/to/next/' + selectedValue);
    });
});
```

You'll need to figure out on your own the best way to replace the selected value. You might prefer to do some sort of regex on the current link, only include a partial link as the href to begin with, etc.